# What are the security risks if I disclose database field name to web user interface?

Tags: sql, database, security, web

I want make the program more simple, so I use table's field name as name in input html,

And then I can save some time for mapping input name to database field name

But, are there security risks if user know my field name?

(Suppose SQL injection have handled in the server program)

---

Update 1:

I am not going to around the field name validation

I just don't want to do something like this

```
$uid=$_POST['user_id'];
$ufname=$_POST['user_first_name'];
$ulname=$_POST['user_last_name'];
```

If I do this

```
$user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
$user_first_name=$_POST['user_first_name'];
$user_first_name=$_POST['user_last_name'];
```

I can save coding time, and don't need to think two names for one data, and reduce bug.

and I can also do something like this to save more time as I just type the name once.

```
$validField=array("user_id","user_first_name","user_last_name");

foreach ($validField as $field) {
    $orm[$field]=$field;
}
```

This can also valid the field name

so I think that hacks are no way to get my unpublished fields

Answer (score 2):

> I can save some time for mapping input name to database field name.

If you *save* time mapping input names to database field names, you would need to *spend* a roughly equivalent time validating that the field names are, in fact, among the fields that the users can access in your database. There is no way around this validation, because otherwise your DB is exposed to hacks that try and get your unpublished fields, such as IDs and hashes. This is pretty bad, so you would need to build that validation layer.

On the other hand, if you do a mapping from meaningless IDs to meaningful, then you do not need validation, because it is your program that produced the meaningful IDs. Essentially, the validation step is built into the process.